# Using preg_replace to remove everything except content between quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've got the following shortcode that I'm trying to run a preg_replace on, to get the title value.

```
[tab title="Emergency Contact" important="true"]
```

Currently, I use the below filter:

```
$sanitized_title = $tab_title ? preg_replace("/[\”\"\’\']*|(?:&#8217;|&#8221;)*\]/i", "", preg_replace("/\[tab *title=[\”\"\’\']*|(?:&#8217;|&#8221;)*/i", "", $tab_title[0])) : __("Open Tab");
```

This returns "Emergency Contact important=true", which isn't what I need. I'm basically trying to get something like `$title = "Emergency Contact"` and `$important = "true"`.

How can I modify my regex string to do this? I really don't know what I'm doing with regex, surprised I've gotten as far as I have.

One additional thing to note, not every shortcode will have both values. Some alternate examples:

```
[tab]
[tab title="Emergency Contact"]
[tab important="true"]
```

Comment: Are you required to use `preg_replace`? It may be easier with something like `preg_match("/title=\"(.*?)\"/",$string,$matchesGoHere)`

Comment: No, I can use whatever's needed. I'll give that a try later today.

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/lB6jA3/1) ?

Comment: @noob: No need to escape these strings: https://regex101.com/r/lB6jA3/2

Comment: @Jan: Was trying to be on safe side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like:

```
<?php

$string = 'some gibberish here [tab title="Emergency Contact" important="true"] some additional info here';

$regex = '~
            (?:\[tab\s         # looks for [tab + whitespace literally
            |                  # or
            (?!\A)\G\s)        # (?!\A) = negative lookahead
                               # to make sure the following is not the start
                               # of the string
                               # \G matches at the end of the previous match
            (?P<key>\w+)       # match a word character greedily to group "key"
            =
            "(?P<value>[^"]+)" # " + anything not " + ", save this to group "value"
         ~x';                  # verbose modifier
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match)
    echo "Key: {$match['key']}, Value: {$match['value']}\n";
/* output:
Key: title, Value: Emergency Contact
Key: important, Value: true
*/
?>
```

This will look for all key/value pairs in the `[tab]` tag, see [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aE9mL3/2).
An additional [demo can be found on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/S7ybh2).

Comment: @bobblebubble: You mean, I *really* need to give some nasty explanation to this beautiful code. Gosh...

Comment: @bobblebubble: Right you are, satisfied now ;-) ?

Comment: This is pretty awesome, thanks much! What would I modify in order to get it to match my alternates for quotes: `" ” " ’ ' &#8217; &#8221;` I don't see how you're matching for `"`

Comment: Oh, I see it. I'll try and add in my crazy string from the original post here.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm basically trying to get something like $title = "Emergency Contact" and $important = "true".

Try `[a-z]+="[A-Za-z ]+"`.

This is the simplest regex which will match pattern of following format.

`Characters from a-z="Characters from A-Z and a-z including space"`

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lB6jA3/3)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can get the shortcode attributes with using "preg_match_all".

```
<?php
//string
$qoute_string = '[tab title="Emergency Contact" important="true"]';

//pattern
$pattern = '/ (.*?)="(.*?)"/';

$tab_attr = array();
//get the attributes.
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $qoute_string, $data)) {
    foreach ($data[0] as $key => $val) {
        $variable = explode("=",$val);
        $tab_attr[trim($variable[0])] = str_replace('"', "", $variable[1]);
    }
}

//see the results
print_r($tab_attr);
echo '<br />';

//title
echo $tab_attr['title'];
echo '<br />';

//important
echo $tab_attr['important'];
?>
```